# Bank to 45 in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Cleveland suggests charts' aspect ratios 'bank to 45 degrees'. How do I do calculate the optimal aspect ratio and apply it using `ggplot`?

A reference on the concept: https://eagereyes.org/basics/banking-45-degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bank_slopes` from the `ggthemes` package. [Here's the documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggthemes/man/bank_slopes.html).

Also worth reading: [a discussion](https://eagereyes.org/basics/banking-45-degrees) of how well this principle holds up.

Comment: We linked to the same thing. :)

Comment: We did :) wasn't in your first version.